# How to increment alphanumeric string in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have to increment `DSNTESTTEST01` each time by one. I tried `${__counter(TRUE,${SAN})}`, but it did not work.

Please suggest how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

It might be a little bit tricky as basically you need to extract the numeric postfix, parse it (as it starts with zero), increment the postfix and add it back to the literal prefix.

I would rather suggest using `DSNTESTTEST` as a static string and [Counter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) test element instead of the function, something like:

[image: Counter number format]

This way you will get:

[image: Counter JMeter impact]

See [How to Use a Counter in a JMeter Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-counter-jmeter-test) article for more information on generating incremented (or decremented) numbers in JMeter tests

---

You can also consider scripting approach, in this case you won't have to change your script logic, but it is more complicated. Example code you can use in [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) will be:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

String san = vars.get("SAN");

log.info("Original SAN variable value: " + san);

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = p.matcher(san);
if (m.find()) {
    String postfix = m.group(1);    
    NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance();
    format.setMinimumIntegerDigits(2);
    Number n = format.parse(postfix);
    int increment = n.intValue() + 1;
    String newNumber = format.format(increment);
    san = san.replace(postfix, newNumber);
    vars.put("SAN", san);
}

log.info("New SAN variable value: " + vars.get("SAN"));
```

Demo:

[image: JSR223 variable increment]